# (Conjectural) description of rank of elliptic curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

The L-function of an elliptic curve E/$\mathbb{Q}$ is defined purely in terms of the étale cohomology of the curve. If the Birch-Swinnerton Dyer conjecture were true, then the rank of the ellitic curve can be computed as the order of vanishing of the L-function $\text{L}(E,s)$ at $s=1$ (the point of symmetry of the functional equation). So, conjeturaly, we should be able to determine the rank of an elliptic curve $E$ purely with the étale cohomology. However, I have no idea how to do this, any a literature search has yielded no result. My own attempt was to try to compute the derivative of the L-function and was not useful. Can anyone point me to a good source or provide a solution?

Comment: The L-function is mostly attached to the $Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$-module $E[\ell^\infty]$ so at first (without the modularity theorem plus deep conjectures like BSD) you won't read the rank from it. See [p.25](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/J.E.Cremona/book/fulltext/chapter2.pdf) for how they evaluate $L(E,1)/\Omega(f)$ exactly in term of rational homology.

Comment: Assuming that its Tate-Shafarevich group is finite, the rank of an elliptic curve is equal to the rank of the Bloch-Kato Selmer group $H^1_f(G_{\mathbb Q}, V^*(1))$, where $V$ its associated Galois representation. Essentially, the $p$-adic Galois representation sees the $p$-adic Selmer group of $E$, which encodes the rank of $E$ if the $p$-primary part of Sha is finite. Without assuming the finiteness of Sha, I don't think there is a (known) way of computing the rank from etale cohomology.